# What is Android in actual ? Mobile Software or Operating system?

Tags: operating-system

I am too frustrated when i discussed about Android.
Internet searches strongly says it is Operating system but also some searches says it is Mobile software.

What is Android in actual. Mobile Software or Operating system ?
Confused.

Comment: why does the distinction matter?

Comment: It's a mobile operating system. An operating system is software too. Wrong dichotomy.

Answer (score 2):

Its a open source mobile operating systems targeted for mobile devices such as smart phones and tablets.

> Internet searches strongly says it is Operating system but also some
>   searches says it is Mobile software.

That is both correct, software includes OS.

If you think of it in OOP terms, Android will inherit from 'Software' and 'Operating System'

You can read more in the SO [info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/android/info) of Android tag

Answer (score 1):

Android is an operating system, based on the same kernel as Linux.  It is optimized for low power operation, and for a small memory footprint.  [You can get developer tools online.](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)